# Get Top 1 From Data For Every Employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2017

I have a query which produces data like this

```
select c.Id, a.userId as Payroll, c.CurrentLocation, c.Longitude, c.Latitude, c.TextOtherLocation, c.CreationDate
    from PeopleDB.dbo.masterpeople a
    inner join PeopleDB.dbo.masterPeople b on a.manager = b.userid
    inner join PeopleTracking c on a.userId = c.payroll
    where a.Manager = '20090036'
ORDER BY Id DESC
```

```
Id  Payroll     CurrentLocation       Longitude     Latitude    TextOtherLocation   CreationDate
51  20180002    Field Work Location   107.5588565   -6.9077868                      6/13/2020 19:56
50  20180002    Field Work Location   107.5588565   -6.9077868                      6/14/2020 19:56
49  20190026    Office                107.5587918   -6.9077061                      6/15/2020 19:56
48  20190026    Field Work Location   107.5588565   -6.9077868                      6/16/2020 19:56
47  20190026    Office                107.5588565   -6.9077868                      6/17/2020 19:56
```

How can I get just any top 1 data descending for any payroll
from above data, what I want is:

```
Id  Payroll     CurrentLocation       Longitude     Latitude    TextOtherLocation   CreationDate
51  20180002    Field Work Location   107.5588565   -6.9077868                      6/13/2020 19:56
49  20190026    Office                107.5587918   -6.9077061                      6/15/2020 19:56
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select c.Id, a.userId as Payroll, c.CurrentLocation, c.Longitude, c.Latitude, c.TextOtherLocation, c.CreationDate,
             row_number() over (partition by a.userid order by c.CreatedDate desc) as seqnum
      from PeopleDB.dbo.masterpeople a join
           PeopleDB.dbo.masterPeople b
           on a.manager = b.userid join
           PeopleTracking c
           on a.userId = c.payroll
      where a.Manager = '20090036'
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
ORDER BY Id DESC;
```

Note that `a`, `b`, and `c` are *really* bad choices for table aliases.  These should be table abbreviations, respectively something like `mp1`, `mp2` and `pt`.

Comment: thank you, really help

yes of course table aliases with a, b, c  is bad idea, but its just for trial and error

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the [`row_number()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) windowing function to assign ordinals to rows like this.

```
select Id,Payroll,CurrentLocation,Longitude,Latitude, TextOtherLocation, CreationDate
from (
select c.Id, a.userId as Payroll, c.CurrentLocation, c.Longitude, c.Latitude, c.TextOtherLocation, c.CreationDate, row_number() over (partition by a.userId order by c.Id desc) as PayrollRowNum
    from PeopleDB.dbo.masterpeople a
    inner join PeopleDB.dbo.masterPeople b on a.manager = b.userid
    inner join PeopleTracking c on a.userId = c.payroll
    where a.Manager = '20090036') as PayrollData where PayrollRowNum = 1
```

This assigns original numbers to each of the rows, with the numbering resetting for each `a.userId`. Then retrieve only the "first" one based on descending `c.Id` within each `a.userId` "group".